# Troubles finding the position of a char in a string

Tags: c

My function is returning an incorrect value.

I tried to do this code in the main function and it works

```
int f_char(char a[], char l)
{
    int pos= 0;
    for(int i=0; a[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==l){
            pos= i+1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

int main()
{
    char a[256]= "Hola";
    char l= 'l';

    f_char(a, l);
    printf("%c is in the position %d", l, f_char);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected result is:

> l is in the 3 position

But it gives me:

> l is in the 4199401 position

Comment: How are you calling this function?  You're probably not passing a null terminated string.

Comment: Can you paste up `int main` too?

Comment: @Cid Show a minimal compiled example that reproduces the problem. Take into account that positions in C start from 0.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Somewhat un-idiomatically the function returns index+1 if found and 0 if not.

Comment: Turn on **all** your compiler warnings, and mind them.

Comment: No need for both `i` and `pos`. Using just one variable will improve your code.

Comment: The function should work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem in the function.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
int f_char(char a[], char l)
{
    int pos= 0;
    for(int i=0; a[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==l){
            pos= i+1;
            break;
        }
    }
    return pos;
}

int main(){
    char *sen= "abcd";
    char x = 'c';
   printf("%d", f_char(sen, x));   

    return 0;
}
```

---

output : 3

Comment: int main()
    {
        char a[256]= "Hola";
        char l= 'l';
    
    
       f_char(a, l);
    
        printf("%c is in the position %d", l, f_char);
    
        return 0;

Comment: @Cid That is not how return codes in C work. You're printing the address of the function, not the return value. The correct code would be: `int main() { char a[256]= "Hola"; char l= 'l'; printf("%c is in the position %d", l, f_char(a, l)); return 0;`